# How to use sun.reflect package in jdk9/java-9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am using jdk-9 and I want to use `sun.reflect.*` package in my code but I am getting the below exception

```
Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.IllegalAccessError : class Test (in moudle: Unnamed Module) cannot access class sun.reflect.Reflaction (in module:java.base), sun.reflect is not exported to Unnamed module
```

when I run below sample code using JDK-9

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   System.out.println(Reflection.getCallerClass(3));
}
```

Answer (score 13):

These `sun.*` packages were never part of the official API and not guaranteed to be present, even in JVMs before Java 9. Be prepared for them to vanish completely in the future, not even be recoverable via some options. Thankfully, there is an official API covering this functionality, eliminating the need for inofficial APIs.

Get the immediate caller class

```
Class<?> c = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE)
                        .getCallerClass();
```

Get the n’th caller on the stack (e.g. third, like in your example):

```
Class<?> c = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE).walk(s ->
     s.map(StackWalker.StackFrame::getDeclaringClass).skip(3).findFirst().orElse(null));
```

Comment: This works post JDK10, upvoting for visibility as the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

Works fine with newer OpenJDK 9 EA builds. For example:

```
$ java -version
java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+138)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+138, mixed mode)

$ javac Test.java
Test.java:5: warning: Reflection is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    System.out.println(Reflection.getCallerClass(3));
                       ^
Note: Test.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 warning

$ java Test
null
```

Seems that it was fixed in 9-ea+115 build as a part of [JDK-8137058](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8137058). So probably you are using older EA build. In general @Holger is right: there are big chances that this API will disappear completely in future Java versions, so consider migrating to StackWalker API.

Comment: Indeed, `sun.reflect.Reflection` has moved to the `jdk.unsupported` module. So it will be there at least until Java 10.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov What about Java 11?

Answer (score 6):

**THIS ANSWER IS OUTDATED - CHECK [THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42187227/2525313) INSTEAD!**

A feature of the module system is that it allows library developers to strongly encapsulate implementation details due to the new [accessibility rules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#accessibility). In a nutshell, most types in `sun.*` and `com.sun.*` packages will no longer be accessible. This is in line with Sun and later Oracle stating that these packages are not meant for public consumption.

A workaround is to export these packages at compile and launch time with a command line flag:

```
--add-exports java.base/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
```

This exports the package `sun.reflect` from the module *java.base* to all modules including the [unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module), which is the one that collects all classes on the class path.

Answer (score 3):

```
java -cp classes -XaddExports:java.base/sun.reflect Test
```

Jigsaw (java-9) has modularity concept in which they have designed java.base package for compact-1 and they have encapsulated `sun.reflect.*`. so `sun.reflect.*` can not be accessible outside.
Due to that reason it giving the exception

```
Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.IllegalAccessError : class Test (in moudle: Unnamed Module) cannot access class sun.reflect.Reflaction (in module:java.base), sun.reflect is not exported to Unnamed module
```

Still to provide backward compatibility, they have provided the way to use that package like below.

```
java -cp classes -XaddExports:java.base/sun.reflect Test
```

Comment: The answer is somewhat misleading: (1) compact profiles have nothing to do with it; (2) it fails for all kinds of other packages, too; (3) error message and proposed solution are outdated. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41824999/2525313) instead.

Comment: @Nicolai Your answer is outdated. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42187227/706317) instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the thread with the latest release and changes brought in as mentioned in the [Migration documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-B96BD00F-12A4-493A-9907-2FFE8DA6748C) as well. Appropriately correctly [pointed out by @Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879383/1746118) already though.

The APIs in `sun.reflect` packages that remain accessible in JDK 9 are:

> - `sun.reflect.Reflection::getCallerClass(int)` Instead, use the
>     stack-walking API, see [JEP 259: Stack-Walking
>     API.](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/259)
> - `sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization`

***These APIs are accessible by default at run time. They have been moved to the `jdk.unsupported` module, which is present in the JRE and JDK images. Modules that need these APIs must declare a dependency upon the `jdk.unsupported` module.***

The remaining internal APIs in the sun.misc and sun.reflect packages
have been moved, since they should not be accessible. If you need to use one of these internal APIs, you can break encapsulation using the `--add-exports` command line option. (similar to as [answered by 
@NIrav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41820145/1746118)). 
Though as suggested in the docs, *this option should only be used as a temporary aid to migration.*

Comment: If you are new to java9 modules, it would be useful to know that you have to add a new file into your package, called module-info.java, that declares the dependency on jdk.unsupported. it looks like this: `module com.mypackage { requires jdk.unsupported; requires org.apache.logging.log4j; exports com.mypackage; } `