# Drools compatibility with Java 11

Tags: wildfly, drools, java-11

When deploying an ear application containing a drools kie engine 7.20.0.Final on Wildfly 16.0.0.Final, I get a deployment failure exception that sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory class cannot be loaded. The application deploys fine with Java 8.

I understand that Java 11 has removed support for sun.reflect.Reflection. Does drools rely on it? The drools documentation only says the Java requirement is for Java 1.5 and nothing more.

Is drools compatible with Java 11?

**Solved.** Turns out the removal of sun.reflect from Java 11 was a red herring. the actual problem was with Wildfly 16 which didn't make the module available. Solution was to create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml as follows:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="sun/reflect"/>
                </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

See this post: [Mockito, Java 9 and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541554/mockito-java-9-and-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-reflect-reflectionfact/51592708#51592708)

Comment: I don't know anything about Drools but could be useful if you put the stack trace or actual error in the question. In any case, sun.reflection.Reflection is indeed removed. The only method it defined in JDK 9 was getCallerClass and anyone relying on that undocumented method should move to the StackWalker API.

Comment: Solved by adding a jboss-deployment-structure.xml as described above.

Comment: Can you please add the answer as an actual answer?

Comment: https://nicolas-heron.gitbook.io/droolsonboarding/drools/installing_drools_tooling
Drools 7+ has Java11 support.