# Ignite-code2.10.0Failed to find empty constructor for class: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.websession.PlatformDotNetSessionLockResult

Tags: ignite

I am facing some issue with setting up apache ignite-core 2.10.0 in java 11 environment.
I am getting the below exception, when I am trying to start ignite Using Ignition start method.
{"version": "0.2.0", "timestamp": "2021-08-18T08:08:51.363Z", "severity": "error", "service_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "metadata" : {"category": "xxx"}, "message": "Exception during start processors, node will be stopped and close connections"}
org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to find empty constructor for class: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.websession.PlatformDotNetSessionLockResult
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.constructor(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:1088)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:309)

As a work around temporarily I created the default constructer in the org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.websession.PlatformDotNetSessionLockResult.java class and build the jar from source code. This solved my problem and I was able to proceed. I now need a solution to this problem, so that when I integrate Ignite to build the solution I don’t have to make this change.

Also wanted to appraise you that this is being used in the containerized product which uses java11 and ignite cluster would be started in the same JVM

Thanks,
Pankaj Bhadani

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12483), please check for the workaround in [Connection from Ignite Client in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59407347/connection-from-ignite-client-in-docker-container-to-ignite-server-in-another-do) question.